# Render to jpg/png WPF controls and WindowsFormHost containing WinForms controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have a WPF form that contains a *WindowsFormsHost* control.

This *WindowsFormsHost* control is added intentionally to add ActiveX/WinForms controls at the same time.

Eventually, I have to take a picture of the form that contains the *WindowsFormsHost* control, here is the problem.
I've found how to save wpf ( [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470841/easiest-way-of-saving-wpf-image-control-to-a-file) ) as jpg and winforms as jpg ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756954/using-rendertargetbitmap-on-windowsformshost) ) too.

**From WPF:**
formGrid is base Grid in WPF form

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)formGrid.ActualWidth, (int)formGrid.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
rtb.Render(formGrid);

JpegBitmapEncoder jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"c:\testwpf.jpg"))
{
     jpg.Save(stm);
}
```

**From WinForms:**
formhost is WindowsFormHost control

```
using (var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap((int)formhost.Width, (int)formhost.Height))
{
    formhost.Panel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
    bmp.Save(@"c:\testwinform.jpg") 
}
```

What I want is to mix/merge, if it were possible, the result of getting both renderings into one single image.

PD: I tried to create a BitmapSource from Bitmap and add it to the JpegBitmapEncoder but I got no successful result.

Comment: "I got no successful result", what does that mean? Does the RenderTargetBitmap not show the WindowsFormsHost and its child?

Comment: @Clemens exactly, RenderTargetBitmap only shows the WPF controls and WindowsFormsHost control is excluded from the picture.   
I only obtain data from WindowsFormsHost using DrawToBitmap function.